# How to apply PCA to an image

Tags: python, pca, noise-reduction

I have a graycale noisy image. I want to apply PCA for noise reduction and see the output after the application.

Here's what I tried to do:

**[in]:**

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
# Create patches of size 25 by 25 and create a matrix from all patches
patches = image.extract_patches_2d(grayscale_image, (25, 25), random_state = 42)
print(patches.shape)
# reshape patches because I got an error when applying fit_transform(ValueError: FoundValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.)
patches_reshaped = patches.reshape(2,-1)
#apply PCA
pca = PCA()
projected = pca.fit_transform(patches_reshaped.data)
denoised_image = pca.inverse_transform(projected)
imshow(denoised_image)
```

**[out]:**

[image: pca_result]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/24/0ab3519c5db3ae89a448fe591febe088-full.png))</sub>

I get an array as a result. How to see the de-noised image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to see your de-noised image, you need to convert your data which is represented in some low-dimension using the principal components back to the original space. To do that you can use the `inverse_transform()` function. As you can see from the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.inverse_transform), this function will accept the projected data and return an array like the original image. So you can do something like,

```
denoised_image = pca.inverse_transform(projected)
# then view denoised_image
```

Edit:

Here are some of the issues to look in to:

1. You have `53824` patches from your original image with sizes `(25,25)`. In order to reshape you data and pass it to PCA, as you can see from the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit_transform), you need to pass an array of size `(n_samples, n_features)`. Your number of samples is 53824. So patches reshaped should be:

```
patches_reshaped = patches.reshape(patches.shape[0],-1)
# this should return a (53824, 625) shaped data
```

2. Now you use this reshaped data and transform it using PCA and inverse transform to get the data in your original domain. After doing that, your `denoised_image` is a set of reconstructed patches. You will need to combine these patches to get an image using the function `image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d` [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d.html) is the documentation. So you can do something like,

```
denoised_image = image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d(denoised_image.reshape(-1,25,25), grayscale_image.shape)
```

Now you can view the `denoised_image`, which should look like `grayscale_image`.

Comment: Is there a way to see the eigenvectors in my projected image? Should it be done that before or after doing inverse_transform?

Comment: You can reshape the eigenvectors into your image size (h,w) and display them, which are called eigenfaces in the case of face detection. But these images will not look like natural images. One more thing you can do is do the inverse transform with only the eigenvector of interest and see how much of the variance is explained or see the reconstruction error.

Comment: I'm getting a line instead of an image when I do inverse_transform. What I did is I added your line of code at the end of mine as stated in the question.Then display image with imshow(denoised_image)

Comment: what do you get when you display ````patches_reshaped ````? You are essentially reconstructing this data.